# Changing view gives me an error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a list that I have saved to a file in SPD2010. When I upload that list to another site in the same site collection it works fine.
When I make an amendment to the view it suddenly gives me error correlation ID on all the original existing pages hosting the web part but not the page in the different site where I have added the new web part displaying the list.
This has happened twice now, is there something I am missing?
The error in the log:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, thought the image would be enlarged.

Comment: how you save the list, save as tempalte? what template is being used for site collection?

Comment: If I save the list as a template and include the content will the list be dynamically updated with entries made in the original list?

Comment: it will not, unless you have some lookups and you are creating the list in same site.